# A PDF field open in a new window of Drupal

Tags: files

I add a field which type is PDF. When I click the PDF file, I want the PDF file to open in a new window (using `target="_blank"`).

How do I add such `target="_blank"` to the a label?

Comment: In tour theme's `template.php` or in a custom module, [override](https://drupal.org/node/11811) [the `theme_file_link()` theme hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7) to add a `target="_blank"` attribute to your file links.

Comment: how to  override  it .could you give me with more details. thank you,if the theme is test. how to write the  override function?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a quick fix for ALL pdf links on your site you could use a little bit of javascript to accomplish this as well.  This snippet finds all URLs ending in .pdf and sets the target attribute to be _blank (new window).

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Open PDF In New Window
        $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target', '_blank');
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Since you're looking for just files of your field type you could certainly use a less generic selector, such as `.field-name-field_pdf a[href$=".pdf"]`.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your theme template.php file:

```
<?php

function yourthemename_file_link($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
      'target' => '_blank',
    ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: All implementations of `MYTHEME_file_link()` that I have seen, including  this one, are variations of the [Drupal default implementation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7.x). This one adds a `target="_blank"` attribute to all links. [Another one](http://www.burgerboydaddy.com/blog/drupal-7-open-file-attachment-links-new-window) adds it only to files of certain MIME types.

Answer (score 1):

The [FileField Target module](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_target) takes care of it from now on…

Comment: A nicely integrated and flexible solution, but for it's currently blocked by a  [WSOD bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2819699).